# AngularJS Module Declaration Order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have been experiencing an inconsistent behaviour regarding the module declaration order for AngularJS apps. On my current machine, both of the following orders of module declaration work, while on my colleague's machine, only the second ordering compiles without dependency errors.

**First Order [Breath First]**

*Here modules are declared in a breath first fashion, aka the parent module are declared, and then the dependencies are declared subsequently below. This way of declaring module is reminiscent of the way Python modules are loaded by the interpretor, or of how Java classes load their imports.*

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.services', [
        'app.services.data',
        'app.services.nav',
        'app.services.session'
    ]);
})();

(function(){
  angular.module("app.services.data", []);
})();
```

**Second Order [Depth First]**

*Here modules are declared in a depth first fashion, putting dependencies that are deeper in the dependency tree earlier in the file so that these sub dependencies are already declared when they are loaded as dependencies for a higher level module. This way is typical of JavaScript variable ordering declaration. Variable A cannot use B before it is declared.*

```
(function(){
  angular.module("app.services.data", []);
})();

(function() {
    angular.module('app.services', [
        'app.services.data',
        'app.services.nav',
        'app.services.session'
    ]);
})();
```

So now my question is: **Why is this behaviour different from machine to machine?** My current machine is under Ubuntu 14.04 64bits with an Intel Core i5-3230M processor and my browser is Chrome 51.03, while my colleague's machine is a Windows 10 machine with an Intel Core i5-4570k and Chrome 51.03 as his browser. We are both using the same source code, the same compilation script (gulp) and the same dependencies (angular ^1.5.0).

Bonus points if you also have an idea how I can ensure proper dependency order in my gulpfile without having to manually order them one by one.

Comment: What kind of 'dependency errors' are you talking about? The feature of angular modules is that they shouldn't follow any specific order on their definition. But the module should be defined before it is used with `angular.module('...')`.

Comment: My colleague said the following: "I thought at first that the problem was that we are including a module in another modules dependencies before declaring it. But after further research that seems to be irrelevant; the issue seems to be that a module is being referenced (used in a function) before it is declared which throws an error so this module never gets registered which will then cause the dependency injector to fail because the module was never found."

Comment: JS modules can maintain proper file loading order automatically. If 'compilation script' is just Gulp concat, it makes this a challenge and requires to specify file order explicitly. If files are loaded in alphabetic order, this won't work. I would suggest to stick to proper tools (Webpack/Browserify) for that.

Comment: We are investigating further as we are talking, but everything seems to be pointing to what you just said. We are indeed using gulp-concat and it seems like this is a subpar option with some problems with regards with file ordering.
We believe the behaviour of handling glob pattern may turn out to be different from one os to an other, since gulp-concat most probably relies on the filesystem to do pattern matching.

Comment: @estus, you can move your last comment to an answer. I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm very interested in how you might locate the following function: "that a module is being referenced (used in a function) before it is declared" from your above comment @PhilippeHebert? Did you manage to isolate the reference?

Comment: @tubbsy I haven't used AngularJS 1.x since at least 3.5 years, so I can't say :)
Have a great day!

Comment: @PhilippeHebert lucky you! thanks anyway

Comment: @tubbsy Godspeed mate, you can do it 

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I will not leave a dying framework behind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS modules can maintain proper file loading order automatically. If 'compilation script' is just Gulp concat, it makes this a challenge and requires to specify file order explicitly.

If files are loaded in alphabetic order, this won't work. I would suggest to stick to proper tools (Webpack/Browserify) for that. JS modules don't substitute Angular modules but compliment them.

And the problem cease to exist even for concatenated build if the app is extremely modular (one module per each file/unit) and `angular.module('...')` is banned from use. This approach is highly beneficial with OOP design and 'one class per file' convention.